# Cells going out of Row

Tags: html, css

Last 3 cells are going out of table. How to make them come inside the table.

"UG(Date of Joining)" should be just next to first date picker.

Overall there should be 5 cells in that 1 row.

```css
html,body{
    background: rgb(211, 212, 218)
}

.table{
    background-color: rgb(211, 212, 218);
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
    <table cellpadding="8" border="2" , align="center" style="width: 100%;">
        <form>
            <tr style="background-color: royalblue;">
                <th style="color: white;" colspan="2"> <tt style="font-size: larger;">Acedamic Details</tt></th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Student Name</th>
                <td>
                    First Name <label><input type="text"></label>
                    Middle Name <label><input type="text"></label>
                    Last Name <label><input type="text"></label>
                </td>
            </tr>
            

            <tr>
                <th>UG (Date of Joining)</th>
                <td><input type="date"></td>
                <th>UG (Date of Joining)</th>
                <td><input type="date"></td>
                <td>
                  <button title="button title" class="action primary tocart" onclick=" window.open('marks.html'); return false;">Upload Marks</button>
                </td>
              </tr>

        </form>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: You need to share your CSS code to understand the cause of the problem.

Comment: If you click Run code snippet, you can see what your original code snipppet shows those of us without the rest of your code; not a whole heck of a lot. Please provide a [mre].

Comment: @HereticMonkey I have now uploaded the full table. You can see the part that's coming out of table.

Comment: @SercanSebetçi Sorry for that, now you can see css file.

Comment: When you [edit] your question, and edit the snippet, there is a box for CSS...

Comment: As far as the question goes, your first two rows are set up to allow for two columns, not five as you claim. With `table` elements, all rows must have the same number of columns, or some columns must span multiple columns to make up the difference.

Answer (score 1):

To make each row in the table a form, you can use the following structure:

[image]

```css
table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

td,
th {
  border: 1px solid rgb(218, 218, 223);
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #dddddd;
}

.inputs{
  height: 25px;
}

.submitButtons{
  height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>ID</td>
    <td>First Name</td>
    <td>Last Name</td>
    <td>Start Date</td>
    <td>Stop Date</td>
    <td>Save</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>
      <form id="form1"><input type="hidden" name="id" value="1" /></form>
    </td>
    <td><input class="inputs" form="form1" type="text" name="name" placeholder="Enter First Name" /></td>
    <td><input class="inputs" form="form1" type="text" name="description" placeholder="Enter Last Name" /></td>
    <td><input class="inputs" form="form1" type="date" value="Save" /></td>
    <td><input class="inputs" form="form1" type="date" value="Save" /></td>
    <td><input class="submitButtons" form="form1" type="button" value="Save" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <form id="form2"><input type="hidden" name="id" value="2" /></form>
    </td>
    <td><input class="inputs" form="form2" type="text" name="name" placeholder="Enter First Name" /></td>
    <td><input class="inputs" form="form2" type="text" name="description" placeholder="Enter Last Name" /></td>
    <td><input class="inputs" form="form2" type="date" value="Save" /></td>
    <td><input class="inputs" form="form2" type="date" value="Save" /></td>
    <td><input class="submitButtons" form="form2" type="button" value="Save" /></td>
  </tr>
</table>

<script>
    /* Scripts */
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @Anim Did the solution I suggested above help me solve your problem?

Comment: Yes, it helped in some aspects. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your table can have maximum two `td` or `th` whereas on the last `tr` you have defined five `td` & `th`. What you really should do is on the first `tr` do `colspan=5` instead of doing `colspan=2` and on the second tr do one with `colspan=2` and another with `colspan=3` and leave last tr as it is.

Your code should look like this:

```html
<table border="1px">
  <tr>
    <td colspan="5">5</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2">2</td>
    <td colspan="3">3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>1</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```